# ggplot2 - separating barplot with two colors

Tags: r, colors, ggplot2

I got data about frequencies each year. I barplotted these data (x - years; y - frequencies) with ggplot2. Now I want to separate the barplot diagram by coloring all bars below of 1980 with red and all bars equal or higher than 1980 with green. How can I do this - below is my MWE with trying to set these borders with scale_fill_manual which is not working because I don't do it correctly.

**Data**

```
dput(allePubs2)
structure(list(Jahr = 1922:2015, Publikationen = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 4L, 
2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 12L, 4L, 5L, 14L, 9L, 6L, 5L, 7L, 
5L, 6L, 4L, 7L, 3L, 7L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 6L, 4L, 14L)), .Names = c("Jahr", 
"Publikationen"), row.names = c(NA, -94L), class = "data.frame")
```

**MWE attempt**

```
cutoff80 <- 
  ggplot(data=allePubs2, aes(x=Jahr, y=Publikationen)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width = 0.5)+
  scale_y_continuous(name="Anzahl Publikationen", breaks = 0:14, limits = c(0, 15))+
  scale_x_continuous(name="Jahr", breaks = c(1920, 1925, 1930, 1935, 1940, 1945, 1950, 1955, 1960, 1965, 1970, 1975, 
                                             1980, 1985, 1990, 1995, 2000, 2005, 2010, 2015), 
                     limits = c(1920, 2016))+
  ggtitle("Cut-Off bei 1980")+
  theme_hc() +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 1979.5)+ 
  scale_fill_manual(breaks = c("1922", "1979","1980","2016"), 
                  values=c("red", "red", "green", "green"))
cutoff80
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question does not contain a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/4303162). It is therefore hard to understand your problem and give you an appropriate answer. Please make your data available (e.g. by using `dput()`) or use one of the example data sets in R. Also, add the minimal code required to reproduce your problem to your post.

Comment: Thanks for feedback. I added data and MWE. Hopefully its helpful and correct?

Comment: Thanks for adding the data and your code! That is exactly what is needed in order to make your question answerable. One small complaint remains: it  is useful to make your example minimal in the sense that you leave out anything that is not relevant to the problem at hand. I think you should have left out `theme_hc()` because it seems not to be a standard function and has no connection to your problem. But all in all you did a good job improving your question.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful feedback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a variable to your data frame that can be used to control the colour of the bars:

```
allePubs2$before1980 <- factor(allePubs2$Jahr < 1980,
                           levels = c(TRUE, FALSE),
                           labels = c("vor 1980", "nach 1980"))
```

Here, I have used `factor` to convert the logical variable to a factor. The labels will later be used in the legend, so it is important to chose them appropriately here.

And now you can map `before1980` to colour much like you mapped `Jahr` to the x-coordinate:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=allePubs2, aes(x=Jahr, y=Publikationen, fill = before1980)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width = 0.5)+
  scale_y_continuous(name="Anzahl Publikationen", breaks = 0:14, limits = c(0, 15))+
  scale_x_continuous(name="Jahr", breaks = seq(1920, 2015, by = 5), 
                     limits = c(1920, 2016))+
  ggtitle("Cut-Off bei 1980")+
  geom_vline(xintercept = 1979.5)+ 
  scale_fill_manual(name = "", values = c("vor 1980" = "red", "nach 1980" = "green"))
```

[image]

I have also defined a manual scale that makes sure that the colours are the way you want them to have. Note how you can link a certain value to a colour as `"vor 1980" = "red"`. The `name` argument can be used to set the title of the legend, and I have set it to empty, as you requested.

I have also simplified the breaks of `scale_y_continuous()` using `seq` and removed `theme_hc()` because I don't know where that function comes from.

Comment: Very intelligent solution! I really like it. One last thing: How can I change legend in following way: remove "before 1980" above, set "before 1980" after red mark and "after 1980" after green mark?